# Does the $\{a_n\}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n - 1} + a_n$ and $a_1 = 4$ . Does the $\{a_n\}$ converge or diverge ? If it's convergent find the $\lim_{n \to \infty } a_n$ .

I'm really confused about the questions like this . I'm unable to analyze recursive sequences generally . The only thing that I found out was $a_n$ is increasing because $a_{n+1} - a_n = \sqrt{a_n - 1} \ge 0 \to a_{n+1} \ge a_n $

Comment: $a_{n+1}>a_n+1>n$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you explain more please ?

Comment: Isn't that obvious ? $\sqrt{a_n-1}>1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes , it's obvious .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose it converged to a limit $a$. Then $a$ is a fixed point so we would have $a=\sqrt{a-1}+a$ and solving this shows $a=1$ is your only solution.

However, you have already said that $a_1=4$ and this sequence is increasing so it can't possibly converge to this fixed point and hence diverges.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from what you have that it diverges. This is because you've already shown that $a_n\geq a_1=4$ for all $n$, so $\sqrt{a_n-1}\geq \sqrt 3$. It follows that the terms are increasing by at least $\sqrt 3$ each time, so they are going to infinity.